# Excel - Use Named Range to Find and Copy Found Words to Adjacent Cell

Tags: excel

I have a long list of sentences, and a long list of words that I need to identify in each sentence.

**Sentences**
Jack goes to the party with Jill.
Jill likes Paul, but he doesn't know she exists.
Jill went to party with Jack to make Paul jealous.
Jill fell down and broke her crown.
Jack came tumbling after Jill because he is infatuated with her.

**Named Range Words**
to
the
party
well
let's say there are over 100 words in the named range.

**Output would be**

Sentences                                               Words
Jack goes to the party with Jill.           to, the, party
Jill likes Paul, but he doesn't know she exists.
Jill went to party with Jack to make Paul jealous.      to, party

Any help is GREATLY appreciated!~

Comment: Please read - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Well cmac, I read the "how to ask a question"....does that make you feel better?  I stated the problem...gave visuals as to what the input and output would be.... So, I am not understanding your major malfunction.

Answer (score 0):

Would a user defined function like this work?

```
Function COMBINETEXT(Sentence_Range As Range, Key_Range As Range)

Dim c As Range
Dim output As String
‘output = Sentence_Range & " "

For Each c In Key_Range.Cells
On Error GoTo errorHandler
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Search(c.Value, Sentence_Range) > 0 Then output = output & "/" & c.Value
errorHandler:
Next c
output = right(output,len(output) -1) ‘Will get rid of first /
COMBINETEXT = output

End Function
```

Comment: Dude_Scott, Thanks so much for your response.  What I did not clearly define above in my outcome visual is that: "to, the, party" would be in an adjacent cell, not combined in the same cell.

Comment: Comment out the output = Sentence_Range & “ “ and added a right function after the loop to remove first /

Comment: If this was the correct answer please mark as answered for other users to know it is solved